# Refund of visa application fees

Tags: visas

My wife and I applied for visas to travel to the UK on 19th October 2016. When we went for the interview, we found out that we did not have all the required papers and we did not submit our applications. We applied for refunds and waited as this waqq going to take a few weeks.

It has now come to our attention that only one refund was received. What do we need to do to claim the other refund?

Comment: I applied from Harare Zimbabwe and we both did get our visas.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not so much a general question as a request that should be addressed to the British authorities.

Comment: I'm very confused. You applied, went to the interview, withdrew both applications, received 1 refund, but then got the visas anyway? How could that possibly work? In order to get the visas you would have had to leave your passports and you couldn't do that if you withdraw your applications!

Comment: @brhans I think a safe assumption is that they re-applied with all the required paperwork at a later date.

Comment: I am baffled that anyone would consider this question off topic.  Since when are visa procedures unrelated to travel?

Comment: @phoog Of course visa questions are related to travel but this question feels far too specific, to me. The asker already knows how to contact the UK authorities and request a refund. The answer is clearly to contact those people again, so what actually is the question?